# Catching react native errors from ios native and log to crashlytics problem

Tags: objective-c, react-native, crashlytics, error-logging

I have this problem that i can't solve. I'm developing react native app. Some one before be working on this project add the firebase crashlytics for a crash logging. But he added to the native sides . Not the react native side. Android native side is catching errors. There is no problem on that side.

Problem is ios side. iOS native side is only catching ios native errors. Not react native red box errors. I don't have a ios native programming experience. How can i catch errors from react native side and how can i log them to the crashlytics ?

iOS native side is program with Objective-C.

Could you help me with it. I'm stuck and deadline is very near.

Thanks.